# Build hyperlink using value in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hyperlink

I'd like to display hyperlinks in my page template based on values in an array.

If the page contains a certain value, I'd like to insert the corresponding hyperlink.

From another question, I've managed to cobble together a script that displays a link when a value is found in a string:

```
<style>
#viewSchoolLink 
        {display: none;}
</style>

<div id="schoolName">University of Houston</div>
        <div id="viewSchoolLink"><a href="https://www.somelink.com/widget=4379">View on Some Link</a></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementById("schoolName");
var text = div.innerHTML;
if (text.indexOf("University of Houston") >= 0) {
    // if so set display to block.
    document.getElementById("viewSchoolLink").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

The thing is, I have like 80-90 schools in my list. I suppose I could create 80-90 separate divs with their own unique links, but I imagine there is a much more efficient way to do it. I have an array I've set up as follows:

```
const schoolLink = {
"University of Houston": "https://www.somelink.com/widget=4379",
"Vanderbilt University" : "https://www.somelink.com/widget=2537",
"University of Dundee": "https://www.somelink.com/widget=2845",
}
```

Is there a way I can loop through the array to find a match in the key and then insert the value from the array as a hyperlink?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementById("schoolName");
var text = div.innerHTML;
if (text.indexOf("key in array") >= 0) {
    // if so display div and use value from the array as hyperlink
}
</script>
```

Or, since the only part of the link URL that is unique is the widget number, could I set up my array like this:

```
const schoolLink = {
"University of Houston": 4379,
"Vanderbilt University" : 2537,
"University of Dundee": 2845,
}
```

and then just build the URL based on the value in the array:

```
var part = value in array
var link = '<a href="https://www.somelink.com/widget=value in array">'View on Some Link </a>';
```

Comment: You have the school name already in the variable `text`.  You can use `schoolLink[text]` to get the url from your object.

Answer (score 0):

to insert any of the HTML using Javascript we assign in the following manner:

```
var div = document.getElementById("schoolName")

div.innerHTML = "<a href='https://www.somelink.com/widget=value in array'/>"
```

if you want to enter the dynamic data in the place of "value in array", then:

```
div.innerHTML = `<a href="https://www.somelink.com/widget=${variable}"/>`
```